# Significant frame drop upgrading from Unity 2019 to Unity 2020

Tags: unity, performance

I used to use Unity 2019.4.22f1, but now that 2020.3.0f1 has been marked as LTS, I've decided to switch to it.

For no apparent reason, it seems like my game is getting consistently lower framerate, precisely, almost like it's cut in half. I used to get 800-1000 FPS in my game but now its around 400-500. I've tested with multiple things that are even more demanding, and where I used to get 500 fps, I now get 200 fps.

It's clear that this is likely a configuration thing, but I don't know which settings to change, if any of them have been.

There is this SX article here which didn't get answered and seems to have the same problem: [Link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/188933/framerate-drop-from-160-to-56-59-when-upgrading-unity-to-2020)

And this article which seems to talk about a similar problem, though it is marked as fixed: [Link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2020-2-0b1-performance-reduction.965363/)

Comment: 1000 FPS to 500 FPS is probably not a significant frame drop. Since the numbers are so high your code is going from something like 0.1 ms to 0.2 ms. If you are really concerned you might want to check your profiler tab to see where the engine is eating up time.

Comment: You would think a 2X drop in framerate is significant, regardless if it's not concerning or not now because it's that high.

Comment: I get that, and if you went from 60 fps to 30 fps that would be massive and concerning. But if the performance decrease is just adding an extra 0.1 ms, then you could expect to see a 60 fps game to drop to 59.9 fps.

Comment: That's a valid point. I'll check the profiler to try to figure out why this is happening. Nonetheless, it seems weird that this would happen over a simple upgrade, but I suppose it's possible they made some major changes that would result in this behavior.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask, What are the more demanding things you added? I expect the Unity 2020 camera might be a bit slower than 2019 if they added new rendering features. You could also try testing adding lots of rigidbodies or lots of lights if you want to pinpoint what might be causing the performance drop.

Comment: There is really nothing demanding about my game. I am only using the Tilemap system to draw tiles, and procedurally generated a 100x100 map for testing, which is why I'm able to achieve 1000FPS currently. I switched over the version, and just like that, cut in half.

Comment: There is literally no difference between 500 FPS and 1000 FPS. Anything above 120 FPS will max out the monitor refresh rate of almost everyone. Try experimenting with some scenes which have enough computationally expensive stuff in them to get the framerate below your monitor refresh rate. Do you still see a notable difference? If you do, then you might want to start running the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to find out why.

Comment: The discussion under the second link you posted came to the conclusion that it's the Unity Editor which now takes a few milliseconds longer to render. That means two things: 1. it doesn't scale with the complexity of your game scene and 2. it won't affect what actually matters: the performance of exported games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by the nice people in the comments. Summary:

> The discussion under the second link you posted came to the conclusion that it's the Unity Editor which now takes a few milliseconds longer to render. That means two things: 1. it doesn't scale with the complexity of your game scene and 2. it won't affect what actually matters: the performance of exported games.